# Does creating a tablespace on an NVMe disk improve performance?

Tags: postgresql

Does creating a tablespace on an NVMe disk improve performance?

I currently have PostgreSQL installed on an SSD disk and I bought an NVMe disk to improve query and process performance. I created a tablespace on the NVMe disk and then created a database using that tablespace.

My question is whether this will really help make queries faster. The SSD has a speed of 500M / s vs 3000M / s that the NVMe has. I made some queries with the database using the default tablespace on SSD vs database with tablespace on NVMe and there is not much difference.

Is it necessary to install the PostgreSQL on the NVMe disk or is it not necessary?

Comment: I fond sometimes NVMe works counter-intuitively (slower than SATA SSD): https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102514

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to *install* PostgreSQL on fast storage to speed it up, but placing the data directory on fast storage can only be good.

It is too late to tell you that, but investing in hardware is the last thing you do when tuning a database.

Fast disks will only help if your workload is I/O bound, and in your case it will at best improve speed by a factor of six. Creating the proper index can easily improve performance by a factor of 1000.

To make the best of your investment, set `effective_io_concurrency` and `random_page_cost` to reflect the physical properties of your storage, so that PostgreSQL can make the best of it.

The most cost effective kind of hardware tuning for databases is more RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the first thing I did first set up postgres to improve performance and take advantage of the hardware I have, but I was excited that with this new hard drive I was going to dramatically improve performance. LOL

Comment: But, if it's the first query, it will still hit the disk first. If the database has constantly updated tables. It would still hit the disk frequently. I face this issue on DigitalOcean because the "SSD" IOPS is very limited. I end up with high CPU WAIT even when the ram is like only 20% utilized?

Comment: @CodeGuru Yes, RAM won't necessarily protect you from being I/O bound. Fast storage is always a benefit.